# Does Img4j place the text as per the resolution?

Tags: im4java

I come across this [Does Im4Java support adding text to images while specifying font, font-size, and color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724341/does-im4java-support-adding-text-to-images-while-specifying-font-font-size-and)

Does im4j places the text as per the resolution of the image? Ex: 16 pts of a font is smaller in high resolution where as it is big in low resolution. If i want to set the size of the font according to the resolution, will Img4 is able to do it. ex:16 pt given should be converted as per the resolution. also font height would differ from font to font.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In [im4java documentation](https://im4java.sourceforge.net/api/org/im4java/core/GMOps.html#pointsize()) for `pointsize` (which specify the font size) they point you to ([see the documentation of GraphicsMagick for details](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/TypeMetric.html)), which states:

> The pixel units may be converted to points (the standard resolution-independent measure used by the typesetting industry) via the following equation:

`size_points = (size_pixels * 72)/resolution`

> where resolution is in dots-per-inch (DPI). This means that at the default image resolution, there is one pixel per point.

Comment: @testjavadev did you find my answer useful?